# async/await deadlocking when using a SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

According to [this link](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronousnet-client-libraries-for-your-http-api-and-awareness-of-async-await-s-bad-effects):

> When you are awaiting on a method with await keyword, compiler    generates bunch of code in behalf of you. One of the purposes of this 
>   action is to handle synchronization with the UI thread. The key
>   component of this feature is the `SynchronizationContext.Current`
>   which    gets the synchronization context for the current thread.
>   `SynchronizationContext.Current` is populated depending on the
>   environment you are in. The `GetAwaiter` method of Task looks up for
>   `SynchronizationContext.Current`. If current synchronization context
>   is    not null, the continuation that gets passed to that awaiter will
>   get    posted back to that synchronization context.
>
> **When consuming a method, which uses the new asynchronous language    features, in a blocking fashion, you will end up with a deadlock if
>
>   you have an available `SynchronizationContext`.** When you are
>   consuming    such methods in a blocking fashion (waiting on the Task
>   with Wait    method or taking the result directly from the Result
>   property of the    Task), you will block the main thread at the same
>   time. When    eventually the Task completes inside that method in the
>   threadpool,    it is going to invoke the continuation to post back to
>   the main    thread because `SynchronizationContext.Current` is
>   available and    captured. But there is a problem here: the UI thread
>   is blocked and    you have a deadlock!

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {    
        public ViewResult CarsSync() 
        {
            SampleAPIClient client = new SampleAPIClient();
            var cars = client.GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync().Result;
            return View("Index", model: cars);
        }
    }

    public class SampleAPIClient 
    {
        private const string ApiUri = "http://localhost:17257/api/cars";
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(ApiUri);

                // Not the best way to handle it but will do the work for demo purposes
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Car>>();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have trouble understanding the **bolded** part of the statement above, but when I test the code above, it deadlocks as expected.
But I still can't understand why the UI thread is blocked?

In this case, what is the available `SynchronizationContext`? Is it the UI thread?

Comment: Is this from [here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronousnet-client-libraries-for-your-http-api-and-awareness-of-async-await-s-bad-effects)? If so, it would be nice for you to include a link to it in your question and to indicate that most of it is a quote.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but if you make your controller action result `Task<ViewResult>` it can be async all the way down (which scales better with regard to ASP.NET thread usage)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes,i add the link .thanks

Comment: Made the quote text a "quote", so it is obvious your quoting the web site

Comment: @Groo i am very sorry. my english is not good.thank for your Help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I explain this in full [in my own blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but to reiterate here...

`await` by default will capture a current "context" and resume its `async` method on that context. This context is `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`.

Deadlocks can occur when you have a one-thread-at-a-time `SynchronizationContext` and you *block* on a task representing asynchronous code (e.g., using `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`). Note that it is the blocking that causes the deadlock, not just the `SynchronizationContext`; the appropriate resolution (almost always) is to make the calling code asynchronous (e.g., replace `Task.Wait`/`Task<T>.Result` with `await`). This is especially true on ASP.NET.

> But I still can't understand why the UI thread is blocked?

Your example is running on ASP.NET; there is no UI thread.

> what is the available SynchronizationContext?

The current `SynchronizationContext` should be an instance of `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, a context that represents an ASP.NET request. This context only allows one thread in at a time.

---

So, walking through your example:

When a request comes in for this action, `CarsSync` will start executing within that request context. It proceeds to this line:

```
var cars = client.GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync().Result;
```

which is essentially the same as this:

```
Task<IEnumerable<Car>> carsTask = client.GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync();
var cars = carsTask.Result;
```

So, it proceeds to call into `GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync`, which runs until it hits its first `await` (the `GetAsync` call). At this point, `GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync` captures its current context (the ASP.NET request context) and returns an incomplete `Task<IEnumerable<Car>>`. When the `GetAsync` download finishes, `GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync` will resume executing *on that ASP.NET request context* and (eventually) complete the task it already returned.

However, as soon as `GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync` returns the incomplete task, `CarsSync` blocks the current thread, waiting for that task to complete. Note that the current thread is in that ASP.NET request context, so `CarsSync` will prevent `GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync` from ever resuming execution, causing the deadlock.

As a final note, `GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync` is an OK method. It would be better if it used `ConfigureAwait(false)`, but it's not actually *wrong*. `CarsSync` is the method causing the deadlock; it's call to `Task<T>.Result` *is* wrong. The appropriate fix is to change `CarsSync`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
  public async Task<ViewResult> CarsSync() 
  {
    SampleAPIClient client = new SampleAPIClient();
    var cars = await client.GetCarsInAWrongWayAsync();
    return View("Index", model: cars);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have understood cause of deadlocks by async/await more clearly, after I had read another Stephen [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/).

Answer (score 3):

The key point is that some `SynchronizationContext`s only allow a single thread to run code at the same time. One thread is calling `Result` or `Wait`. When the async methods wants to enter it can't.

Some `SynchronizationContext`s are mutli-threaded and the problem does not occur.