# Async call inside `System.Text.Json` custom converter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, system.text.json

I'm trying to build a custom JSON Converter using the `System.Text.Json` library. A specific enhancement of the given converter needs to call an `async` method inside the `public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)` method (link to microsoft help page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0).

The easiest path would be to have the `Read` method marked as `async`, but I cannot due to the `ref Utf8JsonReader` parameter being `ref` (cannot have `ref` parameter in `async` method).

I've also looked for some other possibilities, like blocking the async call:

- [async/await deadlocking when using a SynchronizationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151179/async-await-deadlocking-when-using-a-synchronizationcontext)
- [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)
- [C# Async Task Method Without Await or Return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187544/c-sharp-async-task-method-without-await-or-return)
- [Using async without await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805887/using-async-without-await)

Like, I've read dozens of topic, and tried dozens of possible solution, but I had no luck with any of them. Therefore, I'm back to trying to see if it's possible to have the `Read` method marked as `async` is some way.. But I haven't found any solution so far.

Just to add one thing: I cannot rework my method to be NOT `async`.

Frankly, I'm not even sure this is possible, because even if marked `async`, I should be sure that the method that calls the converter awaits, which is an assumption I don't think I can make.
Therefore, I'm also open to some other suggestions or workaround for this.

EDIT: Due to the comment, I'm posting a sample code, but the complete example would be like my whole program. Therefore, I'm posting a simpler example:

```
public class TestJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{

    private async Task<string> GetString()
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        return "Test";
    }

    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            string value = reader.GetString();
            // The following line is an error: cannot use `await` here.
            // Should mark the method as `async`, but cannot (can't even try because of the `ref` parameter.
            string valueEnhancned = value + await GetString();

            return valueEnhancned;
        }

        throw new Exception("invalid");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As you can see, what I'd like to achieve is the call of `GetString()` inside the `Read` method. But, I cannot mark `async` that method.

EDIT2: Adding image to response a comment.
As you can see, if the method is marked as `async`, it needs to return `Task`:
[image]

Comment: Post some sample code.

Comment: Did it, even if it's a much simple code, but it should explain the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Could you have a separate, local `async` function that does the `await GetString();` call and returns it to `Read()`?

Comment: Yes, I could, but that separate local `async` function would still return a `Task<string>`, therefore it shuld be awaited. The problem would not go away, I would only add a function in the middle... Right?

Comment: Not if you await it - I was thinking something like `return await GetString();` in that.

Comment: uhm, apparently, it still needs `Task<string>`. Or maybe I'm not understanding what you mean. Please, take a look at the image I've attached

Comment: The return type should be `Task<T>` for asynchronous functions (or `Task`). Here it should be `Task<string>`

Comment: Yes, I know, but @500-InternalServerError was proposing to use a local `async` without `Task<string>` as return type, so I tried, but NetCore is not happy about it :)

Comment: this seems like a mess of separation of concerns - can you do the async work after parsing the json?

Comment: @Jolly so what comes up when you change it back to `Task<string>`?

Comment: That the function will return before the function is actually completed, therefore with un uncomplete result. At compile time I might not have problem, but surely I will have them at runtime.
@DanielA.White that is what I'm doing right now, but I actually see more "separation of concerns" with the post parsing solution

Comment: @Jolly: Yeah, sorry - I should probably just have kept quiet.

Comment: @Jolly what's stopping you from just doing `string valueEnhancned = value + GetString().Result;`?